# Convert IntPtr to Int64: conv.u8 or conv.i8?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

I'm working on an `ILGenerator` extension to help emit IL fragments using `Expression`. Everything was fine, until I worked on the integer conversion part. There are something really counter-intuitive to me, like:

- Use `conv.i8` to convert `Int32` to `UInt64`
- Use `conv.u8` to convert `UInt32` to `Int64`

They're all because the evaluation stack doesn't keep track of integer signedness. I fully understand the reason, it's just a little tricky to handle.

Now I want to support conversion involving `IntPtr`. It has to be trickier, since its length is variable. I decided to look at how C# compiler implements it.

Now focus on the particular `IntPtr` to `Int64` conversion. Apparently the desired behavior should be: no-op on 64-bit systems, or sign-extending on 32-bit systems.

Since in C# the `native int` is wrapped by the `IntPtr` struct, I have to look at the body of its `Int64 op_Explicit(IntPtr)` method. The following is disassembled by dnSpy from .NET core 3.1.1:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static 
    int64 op_Explicit (
        native int 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IntrinsicAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionableAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarga.s  'value'
    IL_0002: ldfld     void* System.IntPtr::_value
    IL_0007: conv.u8
    IL_0008: ret
}
```

It's weird that `conv.u8` appears here! It will perform a zero-extending on 32-bit systems. I confirmed that with the following code:

```
delegate long ConvPtrToInt64(void* ptr);
var f = ILAsm<ConvPtrToInt64>(
    Ldarg, 0,
    Conv_U8,
    Ret
);
Console.WriteLine(f((void*)(-1)));  // print 4294967295 on x86
```

However, when looking at x86 instructions of the following C# method:

```
static long Convert(IntPtr intp) => (long)intp;
```

```
;from SharpLab
C.Convert(IntPtr)
    L0000: mov eax, ecx
    L0002: cdq
    L0003: ret
```

It turns out that what really happens is a sign-extending!

I noticed that `Int64 op_Explicit(IntPtr)` has an `Intrinsic` Attribute. Is it the case that the method body is completely ignored by the runtime JIT and is replaced by some internal implementation?

FINAL question: Do I have to refer to the conversion methods of `IntPtr` to implement my conversions?

**Appendix** My `ILAsm` implementation:

```
static T ILAsm<T>(params object[] insts) where T : Delegate =>
    ILAsm<T>(Array.Empty<(Type, string)>(), insts);

static T ILAsm<T>((Type type, string name)[] locals, params object[] insts) where T : Delegate
{
    var delegateType = typeof(T);
    var mi = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    Type[] paramTypes = mi.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
    Type returnType = mi.ReturnType;

    var dm = new DynamicMethod("", returnType, paramTypes);
    var ilg = dm.GetILGenerator();

    var localDict = locals.Select(tup => (name: tup.name, local: ilg.DeclareLocal(tup.type)))
        .ToDictionary(tup => tup.name, tup => tup.local);

    var labelDict = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
    Label GetLabel(string name)
    {
        if (!labelDict.TryGetValue(name, out var label))
        {
            label = ilg.DefineLabel();
            labelDict.Add(name, label);
        }
        return label;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < insts.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (insts[i] is OpCode op)
        {
            if (op.OperandType == InlineNone)
            {
                ilg.Emit(op);
                continue;
            }
            var operand = insts[++i];
            if (op.OperandType == InlineBrTarget || op.OperandType == ShortInlineBrTarget)
                ilg.Emit(op, GetLabel((string)operand));
            else if (operand is string && (op.OperandType == InlineVar || op.OperandType == ShortInlineVar))
                ilg.Emit(op, localDict[(string)operand]);
            else
                ilg.Emit(op, (dynamic)operand);
        }
        else if (insts[i] is string labelName)
            ilg.MarkLabel(GetLabel(labelName));
        else
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    return (T)dm.CreateDelegate(delegateType);
}
```

Comment: It is a tricky corner-case, there is no ideal solution.  What is tripping you up most of all is not seeing from the IL that there are [two distinct conversions](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/intptr.cs,132).  The (int) cast used in 32-bit platforms is not appropriate for 64-bit flavors.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. In x86 mode I get different IL byte array from `Int64 op_Explicit(IntPtr)` than in x64 mode. How is this achieved? I investigated the file path from which `System.Private.CoreLib` assembly is loaded (by `Assembly.Location`), but they are the same between x86 and x64.

Comment: Not the same path, c:\program files vs c:\program files (x86).  But that's not the point, it is an intrinsic so different jitters.  Not easy to see, you'd have to use an unmanaged debugger.

Comment: @HansPassant Again you are right. I didn't know that the "Prefer 32-bit" option is ignored after .Net Core 3.0 and maybe I was confused by that. Indeed there are different assembly files.

Comment: I will write an answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

I have made a mistake. `Int64 op_Explicit(IntPtr)` has two versions.
The 64-bit version is located in "C:\Program Files\dotnet...", and its implementation is:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static 
    int64 op_Explicit (
        native int 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarga.s  'value'
    IL_0002: ldfld     void* System.IntPtr::_value
    IL_0007: conv.u8
    IL_0008: ret
}
```

The 32-bit version is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet...", and its implementation is:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static 
    int64 op_Explicit (
        native int 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarga.s  'value'
    IL_0002: ldfld     void* System.IntPtr::_value
    IL_0007: conv.i4
    IL_0008: conv.i8
    IL_0009: ret
}
```

Puzzle solved!

Still, I think it's possible to use one identical implementation in both 32-bit and 64-bit build. One `conv.i8` will do the work here.

Indeed, I could simplify my task of emitting `IntPtr` conversions, because at runtime, the length of 'IntPtr' is known, (either 32 or 64 to my knowledge), and most emitted methods will not be saved and reused. But I still would like a runtime-independent solution, and I think I already have found one.